# Create a lambda expression for a Query DSL with AND operator in Nest C# (Elastic search)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I have a query DSL

```
{"query":
{
  "match" : {
    "_all" : {
        "query" : "elastic search document",
        "operator" : "and"
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Converted it to a lambda expression, but no idea where to give the operator AND in the query.

```
 var queryResult = this.client.Search<dynamic>(d =>
             d.AllIndices()
             .AllTypes().Query(q => q.Match(m=>m.Query(queryTerm))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on `MatchQueryDescriptor<T>` (the `m` parameter in the lambda passed to `Match()`)

```
var queryResult = client.Search<dynamic>(d => d
    .AllIndices()
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Query(queryTerm)
            .Operator(Operator.And)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My DSLQuery return only one result row but the queryResult returns incorrect result set. Can you please give me any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `explain` to understand why results are included - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html. Can also use explain API to understand why docs would or would not match - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html